# IP switching over PHP crawler

Tags: php, multithreading, proxy, ip, web-crawler

I am looking for a solution to switch IPs automatically when running a PHP crawler. I have a customized crawler which runs with 100 threads but due to throttle limits I often get blocked. Since PHP doesn't support multi-threading I have set up windows scheduler to run the PHP application in parallel.

I would like to assign each thread with a different IP address and welcome any suggestion to overcome this issue.

Comment: It's hard to say how to make your code choose a different network interface since you don't give any clue of what your code looks like. Is it using Curl? PHP streams? pecl_http?

Comment: I am not using any library for the crawler. I am planning to use cURL for switching IPs for each thread but don't know how to program this and if this is a right solution.

Comment: Well, there's no point in asking how to accomplish complex tasks if you still haven't figured out the basics xD

Answer (score 2):

## Multi-threading is possible in PHP

*Some might even call it trivial ...*

```
<?php
define('LOG', Mutex::create());

/* make output when writing to stdout thread safe (so, readable) */
function slog($message, $args = []) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    if (($message = array_shift($args))) {
        Mutex::lock(LOG);
        echo vsprintf($message, $args);
        Mutex::unlock(LOG);
    }
}

class WebCrawler extends Thread {

    public function __construct($interface) {
        $this->interface = $interface;
    }

    public function run() {
        slog("Thread %lu using %s\n", 
            $this->getThreadId(), $this->getInterface());
    }

    public function getInterface() { 
        return $this->interface; 
    }

    protected $interface;
}

$interfaces = [
    "192.168.0.1",
    "192.168.0.2",
    "192.168.0.3",
    "192.168.0.4",
    "192.168.0.5"
];

$threads = [];
$thread = 0;
while (count($threads) < count($interfaces)) {
    $threads[$thread] = new WebCrawler($interfaces[$thread]);
    $threads[$thread]->start();
    $thread++;
}

foreach ($threads as $thread)
    $thread->join();

Mutex::destroy(LOG);
?>
```

The code above gives you an interface per thread from a pre-defined list of interfaces. You would then configure your clients to use the interface set for the thread using CURLOPT_INTERFACE or some other magic.

Further reading:

- http://php.net/pthreads
- https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/6437782 <- **always read this**
- https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/9384409 <- *probably helpful for your specific task*